# Replace/remove parts of a string with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i want to remove parts of a column in pandas
for example.

```
        time                 parts
2020-03-08T17:00:00+0000      1
2020-03-09T17:00:00+0000      5
2020-03-10T17:00:00+0000      9
2020-03-11T17:00:00+0000      13
```

i want that i looks like that

```
        time           parts
2020-03-08              1
2020-03-09             5
2020-03-10             9
2020-03-11             13
```

i tried plenty of commands but nothing works.

```
Index(['Unnamed: 0', 'time_iso8601', 'DE-SH', 'DE-HH', 'DE-NI', 'DE-HB',
       'DE-NW', 'DE-HE', 'DE-RP', 'DE-BW', 'DE-BY', 'DE-SL', 'DE-BB', 'DE-MV',
       'DE-SN', 'DE-ST', 'DE-TH', 'DE-BE', 'sum_cases'],
      dtype='object')



     Unnamed: 0              time_iso8601  DE-SH 
0             0  2020-03-02T17:00:00+0000      4 
1             1  2020-03-03T17:00:00+0000      5 
2             2  2020-03-04T17:00:00+0000      5  
3             3  2020-03-05T17:00:00+0000      6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We usually do

```
df.time_iso860=pd.to_datetime(df.time_iso860).dt.date
df
Out[27]: 
  time_iso860  parts
0  2020-03-08      1
1  2020-03-09      5
```

Comment: got this:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'time'

Maybe because its from an CSV?

Comment: @OlsenBO in the sample data the title of the time column is `time`. In your data the column is called `time_iso8601` according to what you just posted, so for Yorben's code write `df.time_iso8601=pd.to_datetime(df.time_iso8601).dt.date` INSTEAD OF `df.time=pd.to_datetime(df.time).dt.date`

Comment: No Problem @OlsenBO , you can accept Yorben's solution by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.